# Why Scala's transient is not a keyword but an annotation?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

Was it a conscious design decision to have it as an annotation instead of a built in keyword? What are the advantages?

Comment: From http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/106:  _The meaning of annotation clauses is implementation-dependent. On the Java platform, the following Scala annotations have a standard meaning._  ... Java is one of the platform for scala.  (Or that was the original thinking?). The question may marked as offtopic. Not sure a if marking as "wiki"  helps.

Comment: @Jayan that doesn't mention *why*. It only mentions that those specific annotations are standards in Java. EDIT: I guess implementation dependant is another way of saying "Theres no documented reason", but thats not specific to why transient is not keyword in Scala; i'm pretty sure it's mentioning that how the annotations are processed is implementation-dependant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is not documented anywhere, so unless you talk to the authors yourself, you won't get a 100% sure answer.

The only logical reason I can think of is to remove the need for it in the language specification.

Comment: That gives the flexibility in case you need to update what the keyword (or in this case the annotation) means and also offer backward compatibility. You can simply add a new annotation and mark the old one as deprecated.

Comment: @Dragonborn Exactly; same reason why Java now has a `forEach` method for collections, to remove the need for enhanced for loops. It also frees up the name to be used as an identifier, since it's no longer a keyword. If it makes you feel better, I could add this info to the answer